# Saving CheckBoxList checked Items on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a CheckBoxList on my page that I'm dynamically adding items to on Page_Load, using the following code:

ASP control:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="clistSites" runat="server" />
```

Populated by (is called on page load):

```
public void PopulateList()
{
    siteList.Load(siteListPath);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = siteList.SelectNodes("/sites/site");
    clistSites.Items.Clear();

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        clistSites.Items.Add(node["name"].InnerText.ToString());
}
```

Which is working/displaying fine. The next section is where the user uses the check boxes against each item for the next stage, however, when selecting clicking on the "Save" button, this runs the following code:

ASP control:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPreUpdateNextStep" Text="Save and proceed" OnClick="btnPreUpdateNextStep_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnPreUpdateNextStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in clistSites.Items)
        if (item.Selected) SiteList.Add(item.Text.ToString());
}
```

This *should* save them to a list, as defined here:

```
public List<string> SiteList
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ViewState["SiteList"] == null)
            this.ViewState["SiteList"] = new List<String>();
        return (List<String>)(this.ViewState["SiteList"]);
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["SiteList"] = value;
    }
}
```

However when the btnPreUpdateNextStep_Click method runs, **item.select** is always false.

I just want to know how I can make the selected items persist even through page refreshes, and also fetch the text of the checked items.

If you need additional information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call your `PopulateList` method on each postback. This will re-bind your `CheckBoxList` each time you click the button. In the page load do this:-

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   PopulateList();
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, wow such a small thing. I understand why I  had to do it though, thank you! :)